# Why ng-show does not work properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

why ng-show doesn't work properly?
I have code:

```
<h3 class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorsFlag.flag">{{errorMessage}}</h3>
```

And in my controller:

```
$scope.errorsFlag = { flag:false };
//some code
SomeFunction.getSomething()
   .then(
        //success
        function(result){
            $scope.errorsFlag.flag = false;
        },
        //fail
        function(error){
            $scope.errorsFlag.flag = true;
        }
    ).finally(//some code);
```

When I get error in my function,

> $scope.errorsFlag.flag = true

, and on the page element 'h3' must be visible, but when I refresh page, once it's visible, once it's not visible, what problem?
When I inspect the code I see this:

```
<h3 class="alert alert-danger ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="errorsFlag.flag"></h3>
```

,but in console, $scope.errorsFlag.flag = true!;
In my fiddle it's work, but in my project isn't work, I understand that without all code you can't tell what kind of bug, but maybe someone was same bug and rememer how to fix it.

> https://jsfiddle.net/gc3equ1f/1/

Thank you.

Comment: what is the question? could you please update it..with some good explanation..

Comment: Why ng-show not working correctly? If I refresh the page 10 time, it's work only 1-2 time..

Comment: could you share code of `getSomething`?

Comment: Nothing shown would indicate why...create demo that replicates problem. Also show where you are logging the value from

Comment: It sounds like your getSomething method might be occurring outside the angular digest cycle, and that is why the scope is not being updated. However, this is pure speculation since you haven't provided enough information to properly diagnose. I think if you provide a fiddle or the contents of your SomeFunction service, we might be able to diagnose properly.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: ng-bind="errorMessage" have you tried this? I think is a better solution in your case. You don't need this $scope.errorsFlag to display an error... And I think you are getting a race condition in your code, try to use a Interceptors https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: your fiddle works as you intended. I don't think it's an accurate representation of the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **ng-show** directive and use **ng-bind="errorMessage"**

you don't need the **errorsFlag.flag** or **errorsFlag** object.

If you really need to `display:none` this `h3`

you can just use **ng-show="errorMessage"** with **ng-bind="errorMessage"**

```
   <h3 class="alert alert-danger ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="errorMessage"  ng-bind="errorMessage"></h3>
```

Comment: This is a good alternate solution to the means at which he displays data from his service, but I don't think it solves the underlying problem, as there is nothing inherently wrong with his code that would prevent his method from working. The core problem seems to be in updating the scope, which would still be present in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Event I too have faced this issue with `ng-show`. Once try updating the scope using `$scope.$apply()`.
Or you can also use `ng-if` for same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is using the controller as syntax with the this keyword instead. Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hjamal/hu4t0zL8/2/

So your code will look like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('TestC', function TestC ($scope, $q){
    var self = this;
  self.errFlag = {
        flag: true
    };
    
    var someFunc = function() {
       serviceFunc().then(
            function(){
              self.errFlag.flag = false;   
            },
            function(){
              self.errFlag.flag = true;   
            }
        );
    };
    
    var serviceFunc = function(){
            var def = $q.defer();
        
         def.reject("error 404");

            return def.promise;
        };    
    //someFunc();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller='TestC as tc'>demo
        <!--  ng-show="errFlag.flag"  -->
        <h3 class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="tc.errFlag.flag">
                {{tc.errFlag.flag}}
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```